# Sort list based on how another list is sorted

Tags: python

I have 2 list like this:

```
    A = [10, 29, 30, 49, 21, 3, 5, 6]
    B = [y, z, t, e, q, f, h, d]
```

I want list B to sort the same way as list A after sort() function, example of output:

```
    A.sort()
    print(A) 
    >>>[3, 5, 6, 10, 21, 29, 30, 49]
    print(B)
    >>>[f, h, d, y, q, z, t, e]
```

Answer (score 6):

Zip the two lists together. Sort on the first item of each pair, and then unzip.

Comment: implementation `next(zip(*sorted(zip(B,A), key= lambda x: x[1])))`

Comment: Or, `from operator import itemgetter
A, B = tuple(zip(*sorted(zip(A, B), key=itemgetter(0))))`